# MPMoviePlayer : movieplayer.view is behind the view?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios5

In my iPad app,

1. from my view I am opening a popover controller.
2. Popovercontroller (tableview) did select row at index path, I am presenting another view controller.

In that viewController on button click I am adding MPMoviePlayer.

Here is it's coding.

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlstring isDirectory:NO];
NSLog(@"URL== %@",url);

moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                   initWithContentURL:url];
moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;

[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];

[moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
```

Url is Ok. View is Ok. But the problem is Vmovieplayer.view is showing behind my view on which I am writing the code.

I have done bring subview to front.

It's superview.

```
**Super View <UIView: 0x913e700; frame = (0 0; 768 1024); transform = [0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0]; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x913ac40>>**
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:moviePlayer.view];
[moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try: `[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayer];` 
instead of `addSubview`

(you'd have to have a MPMoviePlayerViewController though:

`MPMoviePlayerViewController *movie=[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];`)